# Unable to run executable (.exe) from a ClearCase dynamic view

Tags: clearcase

I have a ClearCase dynamic view. I am able to check-out and check-in all my code files without any issues.

The view contains some executable files. When I am trying to call an executable file in a batch file, I am getting "Access denied" error. When I try to double click on the EXE file in the Windows Explorer it is also throwing the below error.

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What version of ClearCase are you using? (on your PC and on your Clearcase server). What OS are you using for your ClearCase VOB server? View server?

Comment: I am not sure about the OS versions of VOB server and View server. But I have Clear Case 7.1 installed on Windows 2008 R2 in my local.

Comment: OK: check with IT which version and OS are used for the VOb and View server: that will help determining the nature of the mounted shared path used by the dynamic view to access a file. Typically, you would with samba for instance.

Comment: With some research, I found that 'checking-out' the executable file allowed me to run and invoke it from the batch file. This workaround solved my issue (at least temporarily)

Comment: Check your `CLEARCASE_GROUP` environment variable: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11297595/6309

Comment: This can be caused by a missing execute permission for the versioned element.

Invoke "cleartool describe" for the element and check the permissions. If the execute bit (the "x" bit) is not set for your identity, then add it with "cleartool protect", or let the element owner or VOB administrator do it, e.g.

    cleartool protect -chmod go+x <element name>

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to check the element, the view and the user:

- the element with [`cleartool describe`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm) and [`cleartool protect`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_protect.htm)
- the view with `cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview` (see also [Clearcase: How to control whether SUID programs work in a view or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5126056/6309))
- the user with [`CLEARCASE_GROUPS` and `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11297595/6309)

When you checkout a file in a dynamic view, you actually are copying it to the view server filesystem (instead of referencing it through MVFS), so you can execute after a checkout, but it is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of this is the permissions on the element. Do a [`cleartool describe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_ClearCase#Client_types) of the executable file, and any .dll files that it depends on. The describe will likely say you have r-- permissions when the file is checked in.

The fix is to represent the files with `cleartool protect -chmod 555 {filename}`.